# url search parameter values under one search parameter seperated by AND

Tags: javascript, url

I have a url where my serach params are distributed , I should get them under one like

current
`/Search/Search?searchKey&serchkey=key1.......&serchkey=key2....`

expected
`/Search/Search?searchKey&serchkey=key1ANDkey2........`

in the current the search key and its value are distributed among the url,so I want searchkey=all values under one,separated by AND

I have tried writing some methods that can pull all the values and put under one not working correctly.

Comment: What was the methods you tried?

Comment: i have written a method to fetch the value after the particular string and try to put it i an array and tried to join them with AND and also with = but its not working could you help me out by providing a mehtod ..